# Execute a .bat file within the R console

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to Execute a .bat file within the R console?  I know I can run R in batch mode, but am wondering if I can start a .bat file from the R code within itself.  I have googled it and cannot seem to find an answer.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use **system** command for invoking OS commands. Please check [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) for more info.